# Pulling and Running Dependencies in Gradle Task

Tags: java, gradle, jar, dependencies

I'm writing a gradle task that will do the following:

1. Pull a Jar Artifact with a main
2. Run the Jar's main or a method in the Jar

The issue that I'm having is I'm getting is `Error: Could not find or load main class`

I've tried to use JavaExec task to run the method, but it's not finding the main class.

```
configurations {
    Jar
}

dependencies {

    Jar(group: 'com.blah1.blah2.blah3', name: 'nameHere', version: '1.0.0-20190215.210713-17')
}


task runMain(dependsOn: assemble , type: JavaExec) {
    doFirst{
        println ' HELLO THIS IS HERE'
    }
    classpath configurations.Jar
    main = 'com.path.to.Main'
    args '1'
}
```

I expect the script to run the jar, but it's not happening.  I'm not sure if it's because I put the main wrong or what, but I've tried a lot of variations of this.  The main that I've tried is basically the same as when you try to import it through Java.  Ex: java.util.Map or something like that.

Comment: I suspect the classpath is incorrect. I typically set it to `classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath`.

Comment: I've tried that, but it's still giving me the coud not find or load main class error.  Is there a way to check the path to the main in Gradle? or a way to check runnable methods?

Answer (score 0):

So I changed it to classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath and then changed the main to the packagename.MainClass.  My mistake was

1. The dependency I had was incorrectly configured.
2. I messed up the main package path.